# websockets only establish connection from local server, not remote computers

Tags: websocket, port

I am using Node js to build a web server, and it also uses websockets which open on port 3000 to send messages between server and client.

When I go to localhost:8080/ everything works perfectly from my server computer and it achieves a websocket connection...

However, whenever I try to connect to the server at my ipaddress:8080 it loads the html but does not open a websocket port.

I have tried to open up incoming TCP and UDP connections to port 3000 from all computers in my firewall on my server computer however, still, no remote computer will establish a websocket connection, it will only happen when I connect to the localhost from my server computer...

any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Which websocket library are you using? Please show us the code. It sounds like you're accepting websocket connections only from localhost.

Comment: Voting to close, question appears to be abandoned.